# disabling and enabling the radio buttons

Tags: javascript

i have one checkbox and two radio buttons. when i check the checkbox.i want both the radio buttons to enable  and when i uncheck the checkbox i want both the radio button to get disable
below is the code which i have tried

```
 <script>
 function myfunction()
 {
 var radio=document.getElementsByName("disableme");
 var len=radio.length;
 for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
   radio[i].disabled=true;
 }
 }
 </script>
 Notification
 <input type="checkbox" onclick=myfunction() checked>
                <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="1"> open
                <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="2">close
```

Comment: better way use #jquery #Toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if checkbox is checked - in order to do that you can pass the element when your calling the function.

see example below

```
 <script>
     function myfunction(el) {
         var radio=document.getElementsByName("disableme");
         var len=radio.length;
         for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
             radio[i].disabled=!el.checked;
         }
     }
 </script>

Notification
<input type="checkbox" onclick=myfunction(this) checked>
            <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="1">open
            <input type="radio" name="disableme" id="2">close
```